# Javascript: Validate a number with only decimal digits on key press

Tags: javascript

How do we validate a entered number that accepts number with only two dicimal digits? Like, suppose if I enter "12345.655" it should stop taking number after "12345.65".

And if I enter numbers before dot it should accept numbers.

Please suggest a way.

Thanks.

Comment: "if I enter numbers before dot it should accept numbers" - what do you mean?

Comment: @nicael: Let`s say "1234.12" is already displayed, then i`ll edit it with "12345.12".This also should work.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have input like this:

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp="this.value=check(this.value)">
```

You can use this javascript:

```
function check(num){

    num=num.replace(/([A-Za-z])/g,"");
    if(String(num).split(".").length>1&&String(num).split(".")[1].length>2){
        num=String(num).slice(0, 2-String(num).split(".")[1].length);
    }
    return num;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3n2r7/)

Comment: @user3272854 Working. See the fiddle.

Comment: @niceal: Please check it`s not working, enter "1223" then remove first two with 3,to make it "1323"

Comment: @user3272854 So? What happens? Something strange? All is working.

Answer (score 0):

let's say that your input element is `el` , then

```
el.onchange = function(){

    if( parseFloat( el.value )*1000 % 10 != 0 ){ el.value = el.value.slice( 0, -1 ) }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:-

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="number" onkeyup="fixDecimal()"/>
```

Javascript

```
function fixDecimal(){
    var value = document.getElementById('number').value;
    if(value.split('.')[1] && value.split('.')[1].length > 2){
        var number = parseFloat(value);
        document.getElementById('number').value = number.toFixed(2);    
    }
}
```